# Prove that a fixed C raised to the power of k over k! converges to 0 as k goes to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

For any fixed $C > 0$, prove that $\frac{C^{k}}{k!} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$

The hint given is to choose an integer $K>2C$ and examine the ratio in the question for $k >K$

I'm not quite sure how the hint applies here. I tried proving that applying the ratio test to $\frac{C^{k}}{k!}$ shows that it is convergent, and then showing that the limsup as $k \to \infty$ is less than 1 and thus lim$\frac{C^{k}}{k!} = 0$, but I don't think the method works given the hint in the question.

The second part of the question says "Let $f$ be $C^{\infty}$ on [b,c] such that $|f^{(k)}(x) \leq M$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in (b,c)$. Given $a \in (c,d)$, show that $P_{a,k} \to f$ uniformly on [b,c]" and I get how the first result applies here. I'm just unsure how to actually prove that $\frac{C^{k}}{k!} \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $C^k \over k!$ $=$ $1 \over {{k \over C} \cdot {(k-1)\over C} ... {1 \over C}}$

I believe what they were hinting at is the following:

For $k=2C$ you get $1 \over {C \cdot (C-{1\over C}) \cdot ... \cdot {1 \over C}}$ (spreading out all 2C C's under all 2C factors of the k! product)

Now, for any $k^* > 2C$, you have $1 \over {{{k^*} \over C}\cdot{{k^*-1} \over C} \cdot...\cdot {{k+1}\over C}(C \cdot (C-{1\over C}) \cdot ... \cdot {1 \over C})}$ (note the left side factors are greater than 1)

With $ k=2C$ and $k^* \ge 2C$, you can see that the denominator only continues to grow as $ k \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Your ratio test tells you that $ \frac{a_{K+n}}{a_{K+n-1}}=\frac{C}{K+n}<\frac{1}{2}\ $ for $\ n\ge 1\ $, where $\ a_k=\frac{C^k}{k!}\ $, and therefore
\begin{align}
\frac{a_{K+n}}{a_K}&=\frac{a_{K+n}}{a_{K+n-1}}\cdot\frac{a_{K+n-1}}{a_{K+n-2}}\cdot\dots\cdot\frac{a_{K+1}}{a_K}\\
&< \frac{1}{2^n}\ .
\end{align}
Can you take it from there?